# Why the Jumbotron seems too large to not fit the window?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.4

I'm working on a web application in Laravel 5.4 which uses Bootstrap 4.0.0 beta2 for front-end designing.

**The problem is that Jumbotron is too large and I have to scroll down and left to see the entire content.** And I want it to fit the window (*or to seem like a small beautiful photo frame on a large wall!*).

[image: Here is a screenshot from the browser]

1. Here is my blade file

   Get Started

   ## Choose services

   We are much happy to serve you! Please choose  services from below

   Carpet cleaning 
                        Tile cleaning

   Next

In the above, I had used CDN for generating Jquery, Popper.js, and Bootsrap.min.js. **And CSS is generated from the project itself( Bootstrap 4.0.0 beta2 has installed and compiled via npm).**

The funniest thing is that the **Jumbotron works fine when using CDN** for implementing CSS( [followed the official docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) ).

2. The below section is from my app.css file (mylaravelproject/public/css/app.css ).

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600);

/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta.2 (https://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2017 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2017 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */


.jumbotron {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .jumbotron {
    padding: 4rem 2rem;
  }
}

.jumbotron-fluid {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

- I doubt that there is something with the CSS, but can't figure out. Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the font-size. Size of the Jumbotron increased with font-size of text inside it.

This happens due to an accidental change of the variable `$font-size-base: 14rem;` inside  `mylaravelproject/resources/assets/sass/_variable.scss` file.

So,

- I have to change the variable value to default. i.e. `$font-size-base: 1rem;`.
- Once again compiled the whole installed packages: `npm run dev`

Now everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

It is beacause you are setting padding to class `.jumbotron`. This property increase size of `.jumbotron` element(`1rem` left side, `1rem` right side).

Comment: Where I should make the change?